# Passing all possible combinations of arguments to function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have this problem that I thought was a no-brainer, but I am apparently missing the logic behind passing arguments to a function. So, I have this dataframe,

```
id type zone    d
0    1    a   a1   23
1    1    a   b1   45
2    1    a   c1   23
3    2    a   c1   56
4    2    b   a1    7
5    2    b   b1    5
6    3    b   a1    2
7    3    b   a1    9
8    3    b   b1   43
9    4    c   c1   21
10   4    c   c1   67
11   5    c   b1   34
12   5    c   a1   21
13   1    a   a1    3
14   1    a   b1    4
15   1    a   c1   12
16   2    a   c1   10
17   2    b   a1   33
18   2    b   b1   22
19   3    b   a1  334
20   3    b   a1   22
21   3    b   b1   11
22   4    c   c1   55
23   4    c   c1   88
24   5    c   b1   22
25   5    c   a1    9
```

(here it is in the form of a dict:

```
{'id': {0: 1,
  1: 1,
  2: 1,
  3: 2,
  4: 2,
  5: 2,
  6: 3,
  7: 3,
  8: 3,
  9: 4,
  10: 4,
  11: 5,
  12: 5,
  13: 1,
  14: 1,
  15: 1,
  16: 2,
  17: 2,
  18: 2,
  19: 3,
  20: 3,
  21: 3,
  22: 4,
  23: 4,
  24: 5,
  25: 5},
 'type': {0: 'a',
  1: 'a',
  2: 'a',
  3: 'a',
  4: 'b',
  5: 'b',
  6: 'b',
  7: 'b',
  8: 'b',
  9: 'c',
  10: 'c',
  11: 'c',
  12: 'c',
  13: 'a',
  14: 'a',
  15: 'a',
  16: 'a',
  17: 'b',
  18: 'b',
  19: 'b',
  20: 'b',
  21: 'b',
  22: 'c',
  23: 'c',
  24: 'c',
  25: 'c'},
 'zone': {0: 'a1',
  1: 'b1',
  2: 'c1',
  3: 'c1',
  4: 'a1',
  5: 'b1',
  6: 'a1',
  7: 'a1',
  8: 'b1',
  9: 'c1',
  10: 'c1',
  11: 'b1',
  12: 'a1',
  13: 'a1',
  14: 'b1',
  15: 'c1',
  16: 'c1',
  17: 'a1',
  18: 'b1',
  19: 'a1',
  20: 'a1',
  21: 'b1',
  22: 'c1',
  23: 'c1',
  24: 'b1',
  25: 'a1'},
 'd': {0: 23,
  1: 45,
  2: 23,
  3: 56,
  4: 7,
  5: 5,
  6: 2,
  7: 9,
  8: 43,
  9: 21,
  10: 67,
  11: 34,
  12: 21,
  13: 3,
  14: 4,
  15: 12,
  16: 10,
  17: 33,
  18: 22,
  19: 334,
  20: 22,
  21: 11,
  22: 55,
  23: 88,
  24: 22,
  25: 9}}
```

I also have two lists

```
A = ['a','b','c']
B = ['a1','b1','c1']
```

which are the unique `type` and `zone` in the dataframe `df_test`. Now, I've creates a function that will return histogram for the "accuracy" of measurements for all types to `type`. Ignore the fact that the function in itself makes no sense with the provided data, it does return exactly what I want with real data.

```
df_accuracy =[]

def Accuracy_by_id_for_type(distance, df, types):
    df_region = df[df['type']=="{}".format(type)]
    id_dist = df_region.drop_duplicates()

    id_s = id_dist[id_dist['d'].notna()]
    id_sm = id_s.loc[id_s.groupby('id', sort=False)['d'].idxmin()]

    max_dist = id_sm['d'].max()
    min_dist = id_sm['d'].min()

    id_sm['normalized_dist'] = (id_sm['d'] - min_dist) / (max_dist - min_dist)   

    id_sm['accuracy'] = round((1-id_sm['normalized_dist'])*100,1)
    
    df_accuracy.append(id_sm)

    id_sm = id_sm.sort_values('accuracy',ascending=False)
    id_sm.hist()
    plt.suptitle("Accuracy for {} ".format(type))
    
    plt.show(block=True)
    plt.show(block=True)
```

I pass every `type` in the following way:

```
for types in A:
    Accuracy_by_id_for_type(1, df_test,"{}".format(types))
```

and it returns as many histograms as there are types.

A similar function exists for `zone` in the list `B`.

Now, to my issues:

I have created the following function to deal with both types and zone, i.e. "do the same thing" for all combinations of elements in `A` and `B`:

```
df_accuracy_type_zone = []

def Accuracy_by_id_for_type_zone(distance, df, types, zone):
    df_region = df[(df['type']=="{}".format(types)) & (df['type']=="{}".format(zone))]
    id_dist = df_region.drop_duplicates()

    id_s = id_dist[id_dist['d'].notna()]
    id_sm = id_s.loc[id_s.groupby('id', sort=False)['d'].idxmin()]

    max_dist = id_sm['d'].max()
    min_dist = id_sm['d'].min()

    id_sm['normalized_dist'] = (id_sm['d'] - min_dist) / (max_dist - min_dist)   

    id_sm['accuracy'] = round((1-id_sm['normalized_dist'])*100,1)
    
    df_accuracy_type_zone.append(id_sm)

    id_sm = id_sm.sort_values('accuracy',ascending=False)
    id_sm.hist()
    plt.suptitle("Accuracy for {} and zone {}".format(types).format(zone))
    
    plt.show(block=True)
    plt.show(block=True)
```

As you can see:

```
df_region = df[(df['type']=="{}".format(types)) & (df['type']=="{}".format(zone))]
```

keeps only the data in the dataframe for one type and one zone. What I tried was this:

```
for types in A:
    for zone in B:
        Accuracy_by_id_for_type_zone(1, df_test, "{}".format(types), "{}".format(zone))
```

but I get the error:

```
IndexError: Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple
```

What am I doing wrong? Thankful for any insight.

Comment: What is the unit element of what you are trying to achieve? Can you simplify it to a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Yes, please reduce this to a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace:

```
plt.suptitle("Accuracy for {} and zone {}".format(types).format(zone))
```

by:

```
plt.suptitle("Accuracy for {} and zone {}".format(types, zone))
```

or better:

```
plt.suptitle(f"Accuracy for {types} and zone {zone}")
```

To know more about `f-strings`, refer to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings)

Comment: Je t'en prie :-)